# Azure DevOps Incremental pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 components in my project and have 2 different build and release pipelines. For both of them I am mentioning different paths for build and publish. In the release pipeline task "Create or Update Azure Resources" both have same linked and main templates. But here the problem is if i deploy the second component then all the configurations and code in the first component is getting removed... Now i can see only second component configurations. I have selected deployment mode as incremental both in the pipeline and templates as well.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below solution can help you achieve incremental pipeline? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Comment: Hi.. Previously i have only 1 ARM Template for all the resources, but now I have created separate ARM Templates for each resource, then i worked fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since not sure what does your `template.json/template.parameter.json` file and your task configuration looks like, I just share my configuration for you refer.

In the `Azure resource group deployment` task, you can use **Override template parameters** to override the parameter value and this override only affect the current job:

[image]

At first deploy, I am using the name MerlinAngular. In the second deploy, the webappname and serviceplan name is Change-Merlin. You can see the second one result does not replace and override the first one.

What I am using is `template.parameter.json` file,

[image]

then use the **Override template parameters** option to achieve incremental deploy.

[image]

You can try with this way.