# Restrict "Complete" deployment deployment in release pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

[image]Is there a way to only allow "Incremental" deployment via CI/CD release pipelines?

We had to learn it the hard way that when you do complete deployment you lose all of the services in the target environment (all of the resources get deleted).

Please ask in case if you require more information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ARM template to deploy, then you can specify whether the deployment is an incremental update or a complete update.

We can choose Incremental mode when deploying. In incremental mode, Resource Manager leaves unchanged resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template. Resources in the template are added to the resource group.

For details, you can refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes).

**Note**:
When redeploying an existing resource in incremental mode, all properties are reapplied. The **properties aren't incrementally added**. A common misunderstanding is to think properties that aren't specified in the template are left unchanged. If you don't specify certain properties, Resource Manager interprets the deployment as overwriting those values. Properties that aren't included in the template are reset to the default values. Specify all non-default values for the resource, not just the ones you're updating. The resource definition in the template always contains the final state of the resource. It can't represent a partial update to an existing resource.

Here is a related [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901745/azure-devops-incremental-pipeline) you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just want the users not to perform complete deployment from GUI. Please see the image that I have added. Only the incremental option should be available for selection and the complete deployment mode should be set to inactive.

Comment: If you want to remove `Complete` from the deployment mode of the task, I am afraid that this cannot be achieved. The task display is by designed and we cannot modify it.